# How to use participles in front of a noun with object for the participle?

Tags: adjectives, participles

I know that a participle following a noun can have an object.

As like,

> The boy throwing a ball
> Mother goose followed by the baby gooses

However, how can we use participles in front of the noun with the objects of them?

Is one of the following sentences suitable for my question? If it is, what should I choose between two of them?

> The battery-requiring device

or

> The battery-required device

Thank you!

Comment: It should be "by the goslings" not "by the baby gooses"! In any case, the preposition phrase is complement of "followed", not object. A case could be made for treating "battery-requiring" as a compound adjective, but not for "battery-required". Note that "battery" is not the object of "requiring": compound words are composed of two (or more) smaller bases that combine to form a single word. In this case "battery-requiring" is a verb-centred compound whose bases consist of the noun "battery" as the first component and the gerund-participle "requiring" as the second.

Comment: And it's more idiomatic to say _battery-operated_.

Comment: I agree with the last comment: "battery-operated" is far more idiomatic than either of your suggestions -- in fact, I'm surprised it's not lexicalised.

Comment: Avoid Mother Goose if you want hair-raising, blood-curdling, bone-chilling, spine-tingling stories that give you goosebumps.